# matlab coder + tool boxes + laplace transformation

Tags: matlab

I am currently investigating matlab and especially the matlab coder.

My understanding is that matlab coder can ‘only’ use a subset of matlab’s language features (control structures, functions, matrix operations).

Am I correct to assume that I cannot produce C code from matlab code that involves certain toolboxes (e.g. Neural Network) or does more complicated stuff, such as laplace transformation and/or uses/implements sophisticated numerical methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're unfortunately correct about the limitations of matlab coder, a problem I had to deal with when building a control algorithm for C

I know neural networks are currently unsupported. As for the other numerical methods, it depends on what you are looking for.

Check out: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/eml/ug/bq1h2z8-12.html for more info.

Edit: I'm not sure why you want to do a Laplace transform, but it can do an fft which for most applications is close enough

Comment: Thanks. It was just an example. I may not use it but if I have to I could use fft.

Comment: Do you think I can use functions like expint (exponential integral) and generate C code via the matlab coder. Sure I could implement this myself but I am just curious. Thanks.